# Ubuntu could not be installed on WSL

Tags: system-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using windows 11 on AMD Ryzen 9 7900. I tried to install Ubuntu on my WSL, but it fails. The error message could not be googled.

I installed using below code:

```
wsl --install -d Ubuntu-20.04
```

After few seconds, below message appeared:

```
Installing, this may take a few minute
```

After few minutes, below error message is shown:

```
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80072746
```

The virtualization is turned on in BIOS and it shown as enabled in task manager. I would be very grateful if you could help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu documentation:
*As of November 2022, WSL is now available as a Windows Store app for both Windows 10 and Windows 11. This means previous tutorials related to installing WSL as a Windows feature are no longer required.*

Comment: I've installed the most recent version of Ubuntu on WSL using the microsoft store, and my desktop installation is failing on several key packages (see: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/9350). So far I haven't been able to install.